# Objective-C NSURL Something Dumb

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I have an `NSURL` like so:

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"http://www.domainname.com/pdf/035" withExtension:@"pdf"];
```

but it returns `nil` because this file is clearly not in my Resource folder. My question is what would I want to replace `URLForResource` with?

Comment: what are you trying to do"?

Answer (score 0):

The base name of a file.  For example for `file.pdf`, you would use:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file"
                                     withExtension:@"pdf"];
```